# Set model's __unicode__ to display html tags in admin

Tags: django, django-admin

In the django admin I have a TabularInline for a ManyToMany field with a raw_id_fields set. It displays the **unicode**() of the object next to the html input field.

I would like it to display the an email link. So in the **unicode**() function of the model, I put in the html tags to create a link. However, it is displaying the html tags.

Is there a way to tell the admin that the unicode is safe to display tags?

I've tried using the allow_tags property but that seems to only be a ModelAdmin property.

Is it possible to do this without creating a new template?

EDIT:

I've found exactly where this is happening. On line 159 of:django/contrib/admin/widgets.py

```
        return '&nbsp;<strong>%s</strong>' % escape(truncate_words(obj, 14))
```

The escape there is manually escaping it. I've tested removing the escape() and it works. I don't like the idea of editing the django source. How could I get around this without change the source?

Answer (score 5):

If your aim is to just display an email link for the list view, i would suggest writing a custom column for the list view like this:

```
list_display = ('admin_email', ...)

def admin_email(self, object):
    return '<a href="%s">%s</a>'%(admin.email, admin)
admin_email.allow_tags = True
admin_email.short_description = 'Send Email'
```

This is better because you might be using the unicode call at a lot of other places, and the html might cause problems there.

Comment: This does not work. I think I was not clear enough in my question. This is not the display of the model (so list_display is not used, therefore allow_tags does not work). This is in a TabularInline with raw_id_fields. Next to the input, it displays the object's __unicode__ description. So I need it to display that __unicode__ safely.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example, with same end result as sebpiq's using `SafeUnicode`, "A unicode subclass that has been specifically marked as 'safe' for HTML output purposes."

e.g.

```
from django.utils.safestring import SafeUnicode

class SomeClass(models.Model):
...

    def __unicode__(self):

        return SafeUnicode("foo: %s<br>bar: %s" % (foo, bar))
```

Comment: This worked for me when mark_safe didn't. Seems to be specific to using the `__unicode__` method.

Answer (score 3):

You should try [mark_safe](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) on the value that you return. Then the string shouldn't be escaped anymore !

Comment: I just tried putting mark_safe in the __unicode__ definition and it didn't do it. Should I be putting this in as a property to the TabularInline somewhere?